# Changing a column data type results in an index that is too large

Tags: sql-server

In the sql server db table I have a field CarDealerOwner of type nvarchar(255). Now I want to change the max length of the accepted values from 255 to 900 characters.

When I manually try to change from 255 to 900 the sql server management studio pop up with the message:

> Changing a column data type results in an index that is too large.
> ....
> Changing the data type of column CarDealerOwner causes the following indexes to exceed the maximum index size of 900 bytes:...
>
> Do you want to proceed with the data type change and delete the indexes?

Does this actually mean that I would need to recreate index again?
Any other smarter way?

Comment: The error is telling you the problem. Why do you need to column to be 900 characters *and* part of an index?

Comment: The error is clear but increasing the field size is suspicious. Indexes can only be used for exact matches or range queries. A field with 900 characters is most likely used for free form text. It also sounds like that field is used in composite indexes which makes it even less likely it will be useful.

Comment: Hmm, I suspect that you may have a design issue there anyway and `CarDealerOwner` should really be a reference to a table that lists the dealers and includes the name there instead of directly putting their names. [Edit] the question and add a [example], i.e. the `CREATE` statements of the relevant tables and indexes and some sample data for them as `INSERT` statements.

Comment: If you want to search a freeform field you should use free text search indexes. Index or no, `where thatField like '%potato%'` will have to scan all rows to find matches. The index would only be useful if you searched for an exact prefix, eg `where thatField like 'potato%`.

Comment: Note that the maximum key length limit was [increased to 1,700 bytes in SQL Server 2016](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/sql-server-blog/increased-nonclustered-index-key-size-with-sql-server-2016/ba-p/384728), but that still doesn't mean it's a good idea to use it all. Why exactly do you want this column _in the index key_? To support searching, to support sorting, to avoid key lookups, ...? The _reason_ helps drive _implementation_ (e.g. computed column, INCLUDE list).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 900-byte limit on the indexed field size is inherent to SQL server, so you can't change that.

NVARCHAR() columns take two bytes per character, so you could resize your column to 450 instead of 900.

You could change the data type from NVARCHAR to VARCHAR, as long as your data is in Western European languages. That is probably not a good assumption.